# Is it possible to re-use the same blob url from createObjectURL of a MediaSource?

Tags: video-streaming, getusermedia, mediarecorder, media-source

I am trying to get a media source as the src of multiple videos but whenever I try to set the blob url generated by createObjectUrl, I get an error ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND on the second video I try to set the src on. For now to achieve what I am trying to do I have to create a new MediaSource for each video I want to use the src on.

What I am trying to do is to have a number of videos that play my webcam feed with a delay each one greater than the previous (so the first video is the live webcam, the first video has a delay of 200ms, the second one has a delay of 400ms and so on).

So what I am doing is create a MediaRecorder that everytime it receives data (every 100ms) it appends that data to a sourceBuffer of each of the media sources that it's the src of each video. So whenever I play that video with a setTimeout it shows the original video with delay.

So the ideal would be to use a single MediaSource as the src of all the videos since the information is the same and I am just appending the same information to different source buffers.

Here is my code for now:

```js
   navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true
  })
  .then((stream) => {

    const mimeType = `video/webm; codecs="vp8"`;
    const delay = 500;

    const webcamVideo = document.createElement("video");
    webcamVideo.autoplay = true;
    webcamVideo.srcObject = stream;

    webcamVideo.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {

      const recorder = new MediaRecorder(webcamVideo.captureStream(), { mimeType });
      const sourceBuffers = [];
      recorder.ondataavailable = async ({ data }) => {
        sourceBuffers.forEach(async (sourceBuffer) => {
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(await data.arrayBuffer());
        });
      };
      const numberOfReplicas = 4;
      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfReplicas; i++) {
        const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        const video = document.createElement("video");
        video.autoplay = true;
        document.body.appendChild(video);
        const src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        video.src = src;
        

        mediaSource.addEventListener(
          "sourceopen",
          () => {
            const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeType);
            sourceBuffers.push(sourceBuffer);

            video.pause();

            setTimeout(() => {
              video.play();
            }, delay * (i + 1));
          },
          { once: true }
        );
      }
      recorder.start(200);
    });
  });
```

Here is a codepen just in case: https://codepen.io/cristobalbahe/pen/WNYEPjY

I hope I am making myself clear!

Thank you everyone very much in advance.

Comment: Ooof, the logic on this is really funky.  https://w3c.github.io/media-source/#mediasource-attach  Have you tried using `srcObject` instead of the olob URL?  Have you tried creating multiple object URLs for the same MediaSource instance?

Comment: Hey @Brad thank you for your time. It seems using MediaSource as srcObject is poorly supported on most browsers (only Safari has full support for srcObject, weirdly). As for creating multiples object URLs with the same MediaSource instance I get an error with the second video saying "The element has no supported sources."

Comment: Hmmmm, bummer.  I wonder if something in the new Web Codecs API might be able to help you... you could buffer frames this way, for example.  I don't have any sample code for you on this as I haven't used it yet, but it might be something to look into.

Comment: @Brad I have been checking it out, but it is not supported on Firefox 